ERROR: unrecognized parameter "fillfactor" (SQLSTATE 22023) in YugabyteDB
I’m getting the following error when trying to create an index:
yugabyte=# CREATE TABLE DEMO(C1 INT PRIMARY KEY, C2 INT, C3 INT);
yugabyte=# CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_demo ON public.demo USING BTREE(c2 ASC, c3 ASC
) WITH (FILLFACTOR=95);
NOTICE:  index method "btree" was replaced with "lsm" in YugabyteDB
ERROR:  unrecognized parameter "fillfactor"

How to resolve this issue while creating indexes..

In this case, FILLFACTOR doesn't apply to YugabyteDB storage engine.
You can remove it from the CREATE INDEX statement.
